# What is the best way to test C++ android apps written using visual studio. Without upgrading to windows pro

Tags: java, android, c++, visual-studio, powershell

This is the scenario, I am writing C++ applications, and would like them to be multi platform; therefore, I am using visual studio (2017 RC). Due to the fact I don't want to upgrade my PC to windows 10 pro I can't use the emulator that Microsoft provides, so I need to come up with a solution, which is:

1) write the c++ application using visual studio

2) copy that code into android studio then compile and run to test the code

This method works because once the code is in Android studio it is easy to compile and run on the android emulator; unfortunately, it is a tedious process. What I would like to know is would it be best to write a shell script, java program, C++ program, or other program to automate this process. If you think a shell script would be best please provide an example, because I suck at using shells (Note the platform is windows). Please describe why your method is best, and I'll mark correct the answer that appears to be the best solution. Lastly you should know the process will be done many times (every time I make a change to the code worthy of testing).

If you need more information ask in the comments and I will provide it if I can. Also note if you have a better solution than copying the code into Android studio those answers will be acceptable to.

Comment: you must use an emulator, and not debug on an actual device? If not, I would suggest looking into Nvidia Nsight, which you can debug with right from VS.

Comment: @MuertoExcobito This is the first time I've heard of Nvidia Nsight, it looks quite interesting. After looking at the info page briefly, I noticed it would be quite helpful for graphics processing, and would probably be a good solution for rendering the UI, and other graphics. Do you think it would be best to write the core of applications in visual studio, and render graphics using Nvidia Nsight. Then just write the UI's in different IDE's (ex android studio), and test them there?

Comment: Should have been more specific, perhaps you got to the wrong thing. There is Nvidia Nsight, and Nvidia Nsight Tegra, which although have very similar names, a very different things. (https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-nsight-tegra). The Tegra version is essentially an extension to visual studio, which allows compilation and debugging of Android NDK projects within Visual Studio.

Comment: @MuertoExcobito I did a bit more reading. It looks like Nvidia Nsight Tegra, and Nvidia Nsight would both be quite helpful. Then instead of using a emulator I could just create an APK, and run it on my android phone. If you write an answer that says to use Nvidia Nsight, and or Nvidia Nsight Tegra, and how you'd test the programs you've written I'll mark it as right, so you get points. When I say test I mean test the user experience ex, export apk then run on an android device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using Nvidia Nsight Tegra, as long as you are willing to test on actual hardware, and not an emulator.

> Develop, build, debug and deploy native applications for Android, the world's most popular operating system, using Microsoft Visual Studio, the world’s most popular integrated development environment.

The workflow is quite similar in Nvidia Nsight Tegra as it is for native Windows development, except for the extra toolbar to determine the target hardware.